# How to Get a Clear PlayGround file Xcode 12.3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When I first create a playground page I get these lines of codes automatically. This is the default one.

```
//: [Previous](@previous)

import Foundation

var str = "Hello, playground"

//: [Next](@next)
```

But I want to get simply below rather than above, is that possible? Are there any preferences for that at Xcode?

```
import UIKit
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the existing XCode template or copy the existing template, edit the template and make it your own one.

Option 1. Edit existing blank playground template.

Go to :
`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/Library/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/iOS/Playground/Blank___FileMenu.xctemplate`

Double click to open `___FILEBASENAME___.playground`

Edit this file (After open if the file not visible then the select file from the left sidebar).

And, in the last save file and restart Xcode.

Option 2. Copy `Blank___FileMenu.xctemplate` folder and give your own name and change as per your requirement.